# (a) Prove that for every $n\geq 1$, the following holds (here we put $u_0=0$) $\sum_{k=1}^n u_k=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(u_k-u_{k-1})+(n+1)u_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The following result is proved: if $(S_n)_{n\geq 1}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nu_k$ converges to $l$ and if furthermore $$|u_{n+1}-u_n|=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
then $(u_n)$ converges to $l$

(a) Prove that for every $n\geq 1$, the following holds (here we put $u_0=0$)
$$\sum_{k=1}^n u_k=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(u_k-u_{k-1})+(n+1)u_n$$

(b) Conclude

---

For the question (a) I have tried to use induction to prove but I’m not sure.
For question (b) I don’t know how to do.

Please give me some hints or some recommendations. THANK IN ADVANCE!

Comment: (a) you are correct, induction is the way to go. For (b), divide both sides of (a) by $n$ and then find an argument that $$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n k(u_k-u_{k-1})\to 0.$$

Comment: Hint: the problem is about Abel transformation for series (summation by parts) and Cesaro summation. Of course, you can solve it from scratch, reinventing the ideas behind the aformentioned principles.

Answer (score 1):

Part a is just
a standard manipulation of
summations.
Here is part.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(u_k-u_{k-1})
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}ku_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}ku_{k-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}ku_k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)u_{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}ku_k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_{k}\\
&=nu_n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}ku_k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}ku_{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_{k}\\
&=nu_n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}u_{k}\\
\end{array}
$

Part b uses a standard
bad-good limit argument
where the terms in the first part of a sum
are bad (i.e., large)
and the terms in the second part
are good (i.e., small).
Separate
$\sum_{k=1}^n k(u_k-u_{k-1})
$
into these two parts
(small $n$ and large $n$)
and use the fact that
$|u_{n+1}-u_n|=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$,
which is equivalent to
$n|u_{n+1}-u_n|
\to 0
$.